# C# WCF localhost The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf, iis-7, .net-4.0, web-config, wcf-binding

I have asp web forms application and wcf service, both localhost. This is config from web application

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:63251/Poruka.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="localhostPoruka.IPoruka" name="BasicHttp_IService"/>
</client>
```

This is web config from wcf service

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to    false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" openTimeout="00:20:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="MyServiceName">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
              contract="localhostPoruka.IPoruka"
              name="BasicHttp_IService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

Upload works for smaller size files (for example 30kb), but when I tried something bigger (pdf size 80kb), I got 413 Entity too large error.
I've tried adding messageSize on client and service, but it's not helping. I also addded to applicationHost file this lines

```
<location path="localhost">
<system.webServer>
<serverRuntime uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

I also tried in IIS manager on default web site->configuration editor->system.webserver/runtime set uploadReadAheadSize.
None of this helped. Is something wrong in my config file or should I set some other property somewhere else? Should I try using wsHttpBinding?

Comment: Can you update your question with the full <system.serviceModel> section of your wcf service web.config?

Comment: In your service config file, try to remove the binding name "BasicHttpBinding_IService", unless you declare your endpoint in services node.

Comment: I've edite both config files

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've defined a binding in the WCF service config file, it doesn't appear that you've actually assigned that binding configuration to a service.  In that case, WCF will use the default settings for `basicHttpBinding`.

Try adding a service endpoint explicitly to the WCF config file, and assigning your binding configuration via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute on the service `<endpoint>` element, like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="MyServiceName">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
              contract="localhostPoruka.IPoruka" 
              name="BasicHttp_IService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

This goes in the `<system.serviceModel>` section of the WCF service config.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try with suggested solution, but still not working. I've also updated both config files including your suggestion.

Comment: @Error - when you say it's still not working, is it the same error, or a different one?